# db2 - sql query column's by day

Tags: sql, db2

I need help to achieve the following result in db2:

```
USER_NAME 2015-07-01    2015-07-02  2015-07-03      2015-07-04 
--------- ----------    ----------  ----------      ----------
User1     36            36          36              36  
User2     52            52          2               52  
User3     38            38          38              0  
User4     15            15          0               15  
User5     0             1           11              21
```

Basically I need to get the total tasks by user for the last 7 days. If possible, the column identifier was the day, and also not shown days with any result.

@Edit

Basically there two tables -  Task a User

SQL:

```
select distinct usr.user_name, count(*) from task lt
left join USER usr on lt.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
where task_name like 'Task1'
and lt.close_datetime > current_date
and lt.status = 'Closed'
group by usr.user_name
order by usr.user_name desc
with ur
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe the tables relevant for the given problem. If possible, also provide a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) in order to increase the chances of getting a relevant answer.

Comment: I edit the post, basically is two tables task a user

Comment: You haven't given *nearly* enough information. Nor have you shown us what you tried, what the error was that you got. It's almost like you told us that a train leave two cities. How many sandwiches can you eat before they meet?

Comment: Please see [help] above, reading many pages, so that you start to understand this site, what kind of questions we answer, how to ask a question, how not to ask a question.  Read other well rated questions.  If you give us the impression you don't understand what you're doing,  then chances are we won't think you'll understand the answer either. And if you haven't shown any effort, how much time and energy would you expect us to volunteer for you?

Comment: Search for questions about [crosstab queries](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Crosstab)

Comment: aka [Pivot queries](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot).  How are you reading data from the query?  If it's a reporting application, you can probably assign the headings yourself, which would mean you could write a static query (since pretty much all RDBMSs require dynamic SQL to change column headings).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, may be?

```
with t (n,s) as (
    select 1, 'USER_NAME 2015-07-01    2015-07-02  2015-07-03      2015-07-04' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
    select 2, '--------- ----------    ----------  ----------      ----------' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all 
    select 3, 'User1     36            36          36              36' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all 
    select 4, 'User2     52            52          2               52' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all 
    select 5, 'User3     38            38          38              0' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all 
    select 6, 'User4     15            15          0               15' from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all 
    select 7, 'User5     0             1           11              21' from sysibm.sysdummy1
) 
select s from t order by n
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether to be somehow impressed, or fear this is some type of desperate cry for help, that you find yourself near the brink. Can we point you towards the nearest Zen meditation center? ;-)

Comment: @WarrenT -- this was in response to the original question, which did not indicate whether the OP had any existing tables to work with. Now it's becoming apparent that there _is_ one or more tables involved, with unknown structure, so this answer may not be the best.

Comment: (nods) ...gotta give credit for creativity & effort, in face of frustration. A lesser man might have been less than kind.  The SQL *was* a step in the right direction.  Hopefully, the question will be improved more, if @tiago still needs help. And, you can always delete this answer, at any point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it's very simple, for people who know's a lot of sql (not me :)), I just solve my problem like this, it's not the best way I know, but I can change datetime in bash, thanks anyway.

```
select tuser.user_name,COALESCE(
( select count(*) from task lt
left join LSW_USR_XREF usr on lt.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
left join lsw_bpd_instance_vars_pivot pvt on lt.BPD_INSTANCE_ID = pvt.BPD_INSTANCE_ID
where lt.task_name like 'Task1'
and lt.close_datetime between '2015-07-13 06:30:08' and '2015-07-13 20:45:08'
and lt.status = 'Closed'
and usr.user_name = tuser.user_name
group by usr.user_name
order by usr.user_name desc
with ur),0),
COALESCE(( select count(*) from task lt
left join LSW_USR_XREF usr on lt.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
left join lsw_bpd_instance_vars_pivot pvt on lt.BPD_INSTANCE_ID = pvt.BPD_INSTANCE_ID
where lt.task_name like 'Task1'
and lt.close_datetime between '2015-07-10 06:30:08' and '2015-07-10 20:45:08'
and lt.status = 'Closed'
and usr.user_name = tuser.user_name
group by usr.user_name
order by usr.user_name desc
with ur),0),

(...)

from (select distinct usr.user_name from task lt
where lt.task_name like 'Task1'
and lt.close_datetime > current_date - 5 days
and lt.status = '32'
and usr.user_name is not null
group by usr.user_name
order by usr.user_name desc
with ur) tuser
```

Comment: Never said it was too complex a problem, merely that the question could have included more info, to help us help you.  For starters, we generally prefer specific information about the input, what you've tried, what problems or errors you're encountering. The more you help us know exactly what the problem, the easier it is for us to help.  This answer gives us something more to pull from.  Very glad you have a workable answer. It *is* a fairly simple problem at its core.  There are simpler, faster solutions.